# Convert jquery to javascript for localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert a small jquery script to pure javascript. Whats the best way to go about it? I keep getting "$(this) is not defined" error.

```
var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
if (lastTab) {
  $('a[href="'+lastTab+'"]').click();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the snippet to plain JS easily. But keep in mind, that this will not work, if the `click` event listener is registered with jQuery, because you can't trigger event listeners created with jQuery on vanilla JS. The reason is, that jQuery uses an own implementation of events.

For converting your snippet you will need `querySelectorAll`, to select all elements by it's `href`, and then loop the found elements to execute `click`.

```
var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');

if( lastTab ) {
    // get all elements by href
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='" + lastTab + "']");

    // loop all elements because it could be more than one found
    for( var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        elements[i].click();
    }
}
```

**[Fully working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/usxnf26x/3/)**
(*posted on jsfiddle, because SO don't allow usage of `localStorage`*)